# Matching algorithm with constraint

Tags: algorithm, constraints, matching

I received a data set with employees assign to departments (which I will call dptA, dptB, dptC, etc.).

Every employee has a department rating for each department (dptA_rating, dptB_rating,dptC_rating...), which indicates how much the employee wants to be placed it the specific department (a number from 1 to 5)

I given each employee a prediction for "how good" he/she will be for each department (higher prediction means better fit).

I would like to reassign the employees in a way that wouldn't harm the original Department Rating distribution, and would increase the Department Prediction.

### Example:

both employee 111 and employee 222 has dptA_rating of 3 and dptB_rating of 5

Employee number 111 is assigned to department A, and has dptA_prediction of 0.3, and dptB_prediction of 0.5.

Employee number 222 is assigned to department B, and has dptA_prediction of 0.6, and dptB_prediction of 0.1.

By exchanging Employee 111 and 222 we can improve the department prediction without harming the Department Rating distribution.

### I Tried:

I have a solution that helped me achieve my goal (improving the department prediction without harming the Department Rating distribution), but I think that there may be better solutions for my problem.

In my solution, I ran on each combination of departments and department_rating and checked every exchange's profit (according to the change in the department prediction), and put all the positive exchanges (those who have positive effect on the department prediction) into an array.

After I gathered all positive exchanges I chose the set of exchanges that would bring me the most benefit.

I repeated this process until no exchanges were selected.

Any help would be highly appreciated, and Thanks in advance

Comment: By *not harm the original department rating distribution*, do you mean that the sum of selected department ratings must not decrease but is free to increase? I guess the number of employees per department should stay fixed?

Comment: Yes. That was my intention. The sum of each department rating must not decrease, and each department has to stay with the same number of employees.

Comment: The algorithm that you describe is a hill-climbing algorithm. It should work fairly well, but has the disadvantage that it may get stuck at a local maximum. In other words, it may find a solution where no single exchange has a positive effect, but a combination of many exchanges would make an improvement. A slight improvement to your algorithm is to start considering 3-way exchanges, i.e. three people in three different departments get their assignments rotated.

Comment: Since nobody seems to come up with a clever idea, you could always formulate an integer linear program (like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Formal_mathematical_definition)) and add your minimum rating constraint. Then, use a generic ILP solver to solve it.